# Easy Maximum-Likelihood problem

Tags: statistical-inference

**Problem**

$F(x)=x^{\alpha}$ for $0 \le x \le 1$.  Where $\alpha>0$ is unknown.

Observed values of x:

0,57
0,81
0,63
0,44
0,31
0,91
0,36
0,65
0,74
0,99

Do an ML estimate of $\alpha$.

**Attempt:**

I find $f(x) =\alpha x^{\alpha}$. I build the ML function which is a product from 1 to 10 of $f_i(x)$. Then I take the log of that. Derive, set = 0, get $$\alpha \approx -5$$ clearly incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If F(x)=$x^{\alpha}$ then $f(x)=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$. However, the resulting log-likelihood will not have a local maximum within the range 0 to 1, therefore, if you get a negative number, the MLE is 0.